# FTP client says directory permissions are 0000

Tags: ftp

I encountered a problem that appears to be related to permissions (same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103860/)). When I looked at the permissions of various directories in FireFTP, they all were 0000, which is obviously nonsense, since all the other pages are served without any problems. I only have ftp access, and I think it’s a Windows server (The header says "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5").

I’ve tried a different ftp client, with the same result. Changing the permissions results in a "'SITE CHMOD 764 [directory]': command not understood" error. A search on Google and SO for "permissions windows 0000" and similar queries didn’t turn up anything. How can I view and change the actual permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a Windows server. Permissions in that numerical form only work on Unix-like systems, not Windows. You'll have to set permissions using a different method, such as with Control Panel software, if it's provided.